# Как найти код, который выполняет JS?

Tags: javascript, меню, css

Кнопки на сайте меняют стиль при нажатии.
Как найти код, который меняет стиль для этой кнопки ?

1. (без нажатия)

   О колледже
2. (один раз нажали)

   О колледже
3. (третий раз нажали, после этого кнопка больше не появляется)

   О колледже

Answer (score 1):

В chrome F12 -> Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> Mouse -> click

Таким образом поставишь бряк на все click events